Chrome is quickly closing after I run this automation code using Python Behave Selenium webdriver
Whenever I run my code, the chrome opens and quickly closes, I observed the chrome browser and when it opens it does not even go the the URL link, it opens and then quickly closes for like a milli-second.
If I remove the Given/When/Then along with the "def" it runs smoothly. I'm wondering what might be the problem when I use Given/When/Then?
Code is written on Python language via Visual Studio code
VS code does not display errors and there is no errors displayed on the terminal as well.
from behave import *
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

service = Service(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

@given('User accesses website')
def accessWebsite(context):
    driver.get("<website URL here")

@when('User enters valid registered email')
def enterUsername(context):
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys("test@gmail.com")

@when('User enters valid registered password')
def enterPassword(context):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/input').send_keys("ABc123$%")

@when('User presses Login button')
def pressEnter(context):
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/button').click()

@then('User is redirected to website main page')
def verifyWorkspacesHeader(context):
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/p')

def after_all(context):
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.quit()

I tried removing Given/When/Then along with "def" and the steps run smoothly, so I assume that the webdriver location is not the problem.
I'm trying to automate the website with Behave since I also want to integrate it with Allure reports.

Use behave's test fixture/setup capabilities and place your webdriver instance in the context.
The behave tutorial documentation actually provides an example for this scenario:
# in features/environment.py

from behave import fixture, use_fixture
from behave4my_project.fixtures import wsgi_server
from selenium import webdriver

@fixture
def selenium_browser_chrome(context):
    # -- HINT: @behave.fixture is similar to @contextlib.contextmanager
    context.browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    yield context.browser
    # -- CLEANUP-FIXTURE PART:
    context.browser.quit()

def before_all(context):
    use_fixture(wsgi_server, context, port=8000)
    use_fixture(selenium_browser_chrome, context)
    # -- HINT: CLEANUP-FIXTURE is performed after after_all() hook is called.

def before_feature(context, feature):
    model.init(environment='test')

You could omit the wsgi parts of the example.
Then in your steps, access the driver through context:
@given('User accesses website')
def accessWebsite(context):
    context.driver.get("<website URL here")


I tried this and the other example on the behave tutorial, I just created for error lines, specifically it says "model" is not defined. . where shall I define model?
